# remove new line \n in large file (10GB)

Tags: language-agnostic

I have large file 1.txt containing:

```
User: Test1
Password: P@sawFia1_f

User: Test2
Password: C99vijJiDB9fo@K!!1
```

I'm using `sed -i '/\nPassword/ s///g' 1.txt` for remove new line with Password: but it's not removing it. Why? The final output needs to be:

```
User: Test1;P@sawFia1_f

User: Test2;C99vijJiDB9fo@K!!1
```

Comment: Same comment as the last time you posted this question - you're using `;` as an output separator for data that could contain `;`s. That's going to make working with the output afterwards much harder than it has to be. Why not just generate CSV with quoted fields? Also, your last question had 3 rows per record, this one has 2 - if your real data has 3 or more then you should use 3 or more in your example as the best solution for 2 lines per record may not be the same as the best solution for 3+.

Comment: Do you REALLY want to have a blank line after every data line in your output? I don't remember that being the case in your previous attempt at this question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the lines are paired like that, you can use the following:

```bash
perl -pe'
   s/^User:.*\K\n/;/;
   s/^Password:\s*//;
' file.in >file.out
```

(It can be used as-is or placed all on one line.)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- every `User:` line is followed by a `Password:` line
- the actual password value does not contain white space
- each `User/password` combo is followed by a blank line
- all other lines in the file are ignored/discarded (otherwise OP should update the sample input to show how other lines of data are to be processed)

One `awk` approach:

```
$ awk '/^User:/ {printf "%s",$0} /^Password:/ {printf ";%s\n\n",$2}' 1.txt
User: Test1;P@sawFia1_f

User: Test2;C99vijJiDB9fo@K!!1
```

Once OP confirms the script works as needed, and assuming OP wants to overwrite the original file, and assuming OP is running `GNU awk`, OP can add the `-i inplace` flag to have `1.txt` overwritten, eg:

```
awk -i inplace '/^User:/ { printf "%s", $0 } /^Password:/ { printf ";%s\n\n",$2}' 1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk, given your provided sample input/output all you'd need is:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print $1, $2 ";" $4}' file1.txt
User: Test1;P@sawFia1_f
User: Test2;C99vijJiDB9fo@K!!1
```

or if you really do need a blank line between each output line:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{print $1, $2 ";" $4}' file1.txt
User: Test1;P@sawFia1_f

User: Test2;C99vijJiDB9fo@K!!1
```

If that's not all you need then please edit your question to include more truly representative sample input/output including cases that the above doesn't work for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the shown structure, of `User` and `Password` lines followed by an empty line

```
perl -i.bak -00 -wpe's/\nPassword:\s*/;/' file
```

Reads the file in paragraphs (by [-00 switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D)), so applying the regex to each pair of lines in a string.

The `-i.bak` changes the input file "in-place" but also keeps a backup (`file.bak`).
If you don't want a backup just remove `.bak` part, once it's all well tested.

---

Or, process line by line

```
perl -i.bak -wnlE'/^Password:\s*(.*)/ ? say "$u;$1" : /^User/ ? $u=$_ : say' file
```

This works with, and reprints, any other lines as well.

If there is only an empty line in between, and which needn't be retained, it simplifies to

```
perl -i.bak -wnlE'/^Password:\s*(.*)/ ? say "$u;$1" : ($u=$_)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)User:[^\n]*\nPassword:[^\n]*' '
RT{
  sub(/^\n/,"",RT)
  sub(/\n/,";",RT)
  print RT
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using GNU `awk`, setting `RS`(record separator) to `(^|\n)User:[^\n]*\nPassword:[^\n]*`(explained further in post). In main section of `awk` checking if `RT` is NOT NULL then substituting starting new line with NULL in it and then substituting new line with `;`, finally printing its value as per required output.

***NOTE:*** Above will print the output on terminal, once you are happy with results you can use GNU `awk`'s `-i inplace` option, change `awk` to `awk -i inplace` in above code.

***One liner form of above code:***

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)User:[^\n]*\nPassword:[^\n]*' 'RT{sub(/^\n/,"",RT);sub(/\n/,";",RT);print RT}' Input_file
```

Comment: Can it be done with 1 line? I've tried, but nothing happening :c

Comment: @savio, sure here its one-liner form: `awk -v RS='(^|\n)User:[^\n]*\nPassword:[^\n]*' 'RT{sub(/^\n/,"",RT);sub(/\n/,";",RT);print RT}' Input_file` and to save it inplace into Input_file try like: `awk -i inplace -v RS='(^|\n)User:[^\n]*\nPassword:[^\n]*' 'RT{sub(/^\n/,"",RT);sub(/\n/,";",RT);print RT}' Input_file` Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using `sed -i '/\nPassword/ s///g' 1.txt` for remove new line with
> Password: but it's not removing it. Why?

You are misunderstanding how GNU `sed` works. In basic usage it does apply changes to each line, latter understand as characters between start of file or newline and end of file or newline, therefore such line does not contain newline. Your task require knowning 2 lines of input before procuring 1 line of output. This can be done exploiting GNU `sed` feature dubbed hold space following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
User: Test1
Password: P@sawFia1_f

User: Test2
Password: C99vijJiDB9fo@K!!1
```

then

```
sed -e '/^User/{h;d}' -e '/^Password/{H;g;s/\nPassword: /;/}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
User: Test1;P@sawFia1_f

User: Test2;C99vijJiDB9fo@K!!1
```

Explanation:

- for line starting with User, save current line into hold (`h`) and go to next line (`d`)
- for line starting with Password append newline and current line to hold (`H`) then set current line content to that of hold (`g`) then replace newline followed by Password followed by `:` followed by space using semicolon.

**Disclaimer:** this solution assumes that every line starting with User is always followed by line starting with Password and every line starting with Password is preceded by line starting with User.

(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)